# FastApi Post Request With Bytes Object Got 422 Error

Tags: python, python-requests, fastapi

I am writing a python post request with a bytes body:

```
with open('srt_file.srt', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

    res = requests.post(url='http://localhost:8000/api/parse/srt',
                        data=data,
                        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'})
```

And in the server part, I tried to parse the body:

```
app = FastAPI()
BaseConfig.arbitrary_types_allowed = True


class Data(BaseModel):
    data: bytes

@app.post("/api/parse/{format}", response_model=CaptionJson)
async def parse_input(format: str, data: Data) -> CaptionJson:
    ...
```

However, I got the 422 error:
`{"detail":[{"loc":["body"],"msg":"value is not a valid dict","type":"type_error.dict"}]}`

So where is wrong with my code, and how should I fix it?
Thank you all in advance for helping out!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FastAPI by default will expect you to pass json which will parse into a dict. It can't do that if it's isn't json, which is why you get the error you see.

You can use the `Request` object instead to receive arbitrary bytes from the POST body.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/foo")
async def parse_input(request: Request):
    data: bytes = await request.body()
    # Do something with data
```

You might consider using `Depends` which will allow you to clean up your route function. FastAPI will first call your dependency function (`parse_body` in this example) and will inject that as an argument into your route function.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Depends

app = FastAPI()

async def parse_body(request: Request):
    data: bytes = await request.body()
    return data


@app.get("/foo")
async def parse_input(data: bytes = Depends(parse_body)):
    # Do something with data
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

If the endgoal of your request is to only send bytes then please look at the documentation of FastAPI to accept bytes-like objects: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files.

There is no need for the bytes to be enclosed into a model.

Comment: That's specifically for uploading files as form data. This is not the same as sending an arbitrary stream of bytes in the body.